# i can't install Rasa on Mac M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-x

I'm trying to install Rasa on my M1 MacBook Air following these instructions.
https://forum.rasa.com/t/an-unofficial-guide-to-installing-rasa-on-an-m1-macbook/51342

However, when I do this code:
`conda env create -v --name rasatest -f env.yml`

I am presented with this error:

```
raise CondaEnvException("Pip failed")
conda.exceptions.CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

What shoud I do?

```
writing src/lxml.egg-info/PKG-INFO
            writing dependency_links to src/lxml.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
            writing requirements to src/lxml.egg-info/requires.txt
            writing top-level names to src/lxml.egg-info/top_level.txt
            reading manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
            adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
            adding license file 'LICENSES.txt'
            writing manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            Copying src/lxml.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/lxml-4.9.3-py3.8.egg-info
            running install_scripts
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
              File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
              File "/private/var/folders/69/rz46t6cs19b9wqr3znsqf35m0000gn/T/pip-install-qd7eh6r0/lxml_37fd30cab9dc408fbbe560ae9225b13a/setup.py", line 207, in <module>
                setup(
              File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/envs/rasaM1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
              File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/envs/rasaM1/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/envs/rasaM1/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/envs/rasaM1/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/envs/rasaM1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 328, in run
                impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
              File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/envs/rasaM1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
                assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
            AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp38', 'cp38', 'macosx_11_0_arm64')
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
        Running setup.py clean for lxml
      Failed to build lxml
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1124, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 78, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 109, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 154, in execute
    result[installer_type] = installer.install(prefix, pkg_specs, args, env)
  File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/installers/pip.py", line 69, in install
    return _pip_install_via_requirements(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/installers/pip.py", line 52, in _pip_install_via_requirements
    stdout, stderr = pip_subprocess(pip_cmd, prefix, cwd=pip_workdir)
  File "/Users/magnus/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/pip_util.py", line 39, in pip_subprocess
    raise CondaEnvException("Pip failed")
conda.exceptions.CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

i've tried this video tutorial as well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXL_LqAY650

if I install Rasa with the instruction on official site of Rasa. It doesn't work with error:
`zsh: illegal hardware instruction`